# Error log is strange in fetch catch code block

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Explanation : 
 This file test-table1.json don't exist and i need proper error log to catch.

Error log for current code is :

> Error in table.tsx 1 : SyntaxError: The string did not match the
>   expected pattern

I want error log like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404". Any suggestion ?

```
public componentDidMount() {

    fetch("./assets/data/test-table1.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch( (error) => console.error("Error in table.tsx 1 :", error) )
        .then((resData) => {
            this.setState({ data: resData.table });
        })
        .catch( (error) => console.error("Error in table.tsx 2 :", error) );

}
```

Comment: why is there a `catch` in between ? here you are returning undefined from first `catch` which means the second `then` `resData` will be undefined

Comment: This is regular for any then you can have catch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in response property statusText with info and i passed like class error arg .

```
fetch("./assets/data/test-table.json")
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.statusText === "Not Found") {
        console.error("Error in component MyTable, error msg : file: './assets/data/test-table.json' ",
          response.statusText);
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .then((resData) => {

  })
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error in MyTable in parsing json data: ", error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import ur JSON file using `import` or `require`

```
import data from './assets/data/test-table1.json';

    public componentDidMount() {
        fetch(data)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((resData) => {
                this.setState({ data: resData.table });
            })
            .catch( (error) => console.error("Error in table.tsx 2 :", error) );
    }
```